# Mongo atlas recommends cloud provider snaphots for backup - Is it effective?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

MongoDB has deprecated the continuous back up of data. It has recommended using CPS (Cloud provider snapshots). As far as I understood, snapshots isn't really going to be effective compared to continuous backup coz, if system breaks, then we can only be able to restore the data till the previous snapshot which isn't gonna make the database up-to-date or close to it atleast.

Am I missing something here in my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud provider snapshots can be combined with [point in time restore](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/cluster-config/backups/#create-cluster-backups) to give the recovery point objective you require. With oplog based restores you can get granularity of one second.

Comment: Hi Joe, as it says in the link, the point-in-time restore or in other words continuous back up is what the new clusters will not be allowed to use going forward. Oplog could be a solution. I will check that

Comment: The combination of cloud snapshots and oplog based point in time restores should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could go on further from here.